# Jasmine Nodejs : Mocking a simple Promise function to return hardcoded data

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I am new to jasmine's mocking stuff.
If I'd say I have a below line of code

```
const resultant = service.getAverageHeadCount(queryString, "53860936", "510");
```

function `getAverageHeadCount()` returns a `Promise`, then how can I mock this function so as to not hit the real code but return some constant.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Create Spy of service.

```
    let serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ServiceClassName', ['getAverageHeadCount']);
```

### 2. Create expected mock result and Fake method callback as below:

```
let expectedData= {
           total: 100
     };

serviceSpy.getAverageHeadCount.and.callFake(function () {

    return new Promise((resolve: Function) => {
      resolve(expectedData);
    });
});
```

### 3. If you have used Test Bed, add service spy entry in test bed as below:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      declarations: [
        ..............
      ],

      providers: [
        ..............

        {
          provide: ServiceClassName,
          useValue: serviceSpy
        }
        ..............
      ],

      imports: [
        ............
      ]

    }).compileComponents();

  }));
```

### 4. Test case should be like below:

```
it('any valid unit test name', fakeAsync(() => {
  //call the method containing the service call code.
  tick();
  expect(resultant).toEqual(expectedData);  // It is assumed resultant is a global variable which stores response of getAverageHeadCount method.
  fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

Please provide more code detail for more precise answer.